# Is the guy with the shotgun at the start of Dark Knight a regular comic character?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

I know the bank is mob owned, but is the manager of the bank a named character from the Batman comics?

This is the character I am referring to:
[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

He's played by the fairly well-known character actor [William Fichtner](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001209/), but he's only credited as "[Bank Manager](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0032981/)" so I doubt he represents a named character from the comics.  When he pulls out his shotgun and shouts

> Do you have any idea who you're stealing from? You and your friends are dead!

I'm sure he's referring to the mob bosses that own the bank, not himself.

Comment: Did anyone else think he might be a "mob guy"? I always assumed he was there as mob security or something. He just seemed to comfortable with the shotgun to be a bank manager.

Comment: Fichtner is a tremendous actor, but it seemed like such an odd choice to pick him for this minor role.